# Convert float to string and always get specific length of string?

Tags: java, string-formatting, number-formatting, string-conversion

How can I convert a `float` to a `String` and always get a resulting string of a specified length?

For example, if I have

```
float f = 0.023f;
```

and I want a 6 character string, I'd like to get `0.0230`. But if I want to convert it to a 4 character string the result should be `0.02`. Also, the value `-13.459` limited to 5 characters should return `-13.4`, and to 10 characters `-13.459000`.

Here's what I'm using right now, but there's gotta be much prettier ways of doing this...

```
s = String.valueOf(f);
s = s.substring(0, Math.min(strLength, s.length()));
if( s.length() < strLength )
    s = String.format("%1$-" + (strLength-s.length()) + "s", s);
```

Comment: See `java.text.DecimalFormat`.

Comment: this format is odd ... how would be look `100000.05` limited to `5`? `10000`? *but there's gotta be much prettier ways of doing this* `String.format("%." + limit + "f", f).substring(0, limit)`

Comment: @Selvin Yes, correct. In my specific case I know the range of the numbers I'm working on, and I can adapt the desired length to that. It's for logging purposes, outputting numbers into "columns" in LogCat so they are easier to read even when the output rate is quite high and the sign and number of digits/decimals are unknown (but numbers limited to a certain range).

Comment: @Selvin Seems to be working, thanks!

Comment: `For the floating-point conversions 'e', 'E', and 'f' the precision is the number of digits after the decimal separator.` — Throw in big integral part and get a long-long output.

Answer (score 2):

From `java.util.Formatter` documentaion: you can use `g` modifier, `precision` field to limit number to specific number of characters and `width` field for padding it to column width.

```
String.format("%1$8.5g", 1000.4213);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

---

Though `precision` doesn't include dot and exponent length – only digits in mantissa counted.

By keeping extra place for dot and cutting extra digits from fractional part if string is significantly wider that could be solved too.

```
String num = String.format("%1$ .5g", input);
if (num.length > 6) 
    num = num.substring(0, 2) + num.substring(7); //100300 => ' 1e+05'; 512.334 => ' 512.33'
```

Scientific format of number always follows strict set of rules, so we don't have to search for dot inside string to cut fraction out of string if sign is always included (or, like in case above – replaced by space character for positive numbers).